# Reinstall and restart Android application

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android application, and I want the user to update the application without Google Play Store.

First the application downloads and .apk file from the Internet, if a new version is available. That part works.

Now I want the application to install the .apk file. I'm using this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(downloadedAPKfile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
Log.d("Lofting", "About to install new .apk");
context.startActivity(i);
```

The Android OS kindly asks the user to overwrite the current application, which is fine. I assume the user selects "OK" or "Install" or something.

After the reinstall, I want to automatically restart the application:

```
Intent startActivity = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
int pendingIntentId = new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, pendingIntentId, startActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + delay, pendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

If I just concatenate these two snippets, the reinstall starts, but instantly the application is restarted.

How do I force the application to wait for the reinstall to be ready, and *then* restart the application?

Comment: Dump your existing restart logic. Add a `<receiver>` with an `<intent-filter>` in your manifest for [`ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED).

Comment: I call `Context.startActivity(Intent)`, which has to have the start logic.

Comment: So, do that from your `BroadcastReceiver`.